Multiplication Operator Version of Spectral Theorem in a Rigged Hilbert Space
(This is a reformulation of a deleted post which didn't quite reflect the confusion i have)
Consider the setting of a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. A function $f \in \mathscr{H}$ can be represented in terms of components in the frequency domain, with each component characterized by a complex frequency $\xi_n\in\mathbb{C}$. The coefficients of these components, $c_n$, are determined by projecting $f$ onto the basis of complex exponentials, via the integral:
$$c_n = \int f(x) e^{-\xi_n ix}\, dx.$$
This projection extracts each component's amplitude, reflecting the function's decomposition across the complex exponentials modulated by the complex frequencies $\xi_n$.
The functions in the space are then:
$$f(x)\sum_n c_n e^{\xi_n ix}$$
The Laplacian operator $\Delta$, when considered within this framework, acts in the frequency domain by multiplying each component of $f$ by $-\xi_n^2$. This action suggests a direct, multiplication-based transformation of $f$ in the frequency domain, thereby implicating $-\xi_n^2$ as potential eigenvalues with the exponential functions serving possibly as their generalized eigenfunctions.
Specifically, for a densely-defined self-adjoint operator $A$ on $\mathscr{H}$, the theorem posits the existence of a measure space $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, a unitary transformation $U: \mathscr{H} \to L^2(X, d\mu)$, and a real-valued, measurable function $f$ on $X$, which together facilitate representing $A$ as a multiplication operator $M_f$, where $M_f$ acts by $f(x)$ on $L^2(M, d\mu)$.
$\textbf{Question:}$ Given the Laplacian's action as a multiplication by $-\xi_n^2$ in the frequency domain, does this scenario fall within the purview of the spectral theorem's multiplication operator framework, particularly in the context of rigged Hilbert spaces? Are the $-\xi_n^2$ values thereby affirmed as eigenvalues, with the frequency domain representations acting as generalized eigenfunctions of the Laplacian acting on this space?
thanks
$\textbf{EDIT:}$ Addressing the comment from @paulgarrett, lets assume that the Laplacian here is defined on a dense subspace, say $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, of the Hilbert space under consideration. And to be sure, the exponentials in the basis have complex exponentials- growth and oscillation.

Very roughly, yes, you are approximately correct... But you need to add several specifics to your situation: for example, maybe the Hilbert space is the collection of square-integrable functions on an interval, maybe $[0,2\pi]$? In this example, yes, the $-\xi_n^2$ are genuine eigenvalues, since the eigenvectors are in the space, etc. Can you clarify?

Thank you for the reply! Let's assume the situation is similar to the rigging $(C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}),L^2(\mathbb{R}))$, so that the complex exponentials live in the dual to the (dense in the Hilbert) space where the Laplacian is well defined. I am going to edit the question to better reflect this.
